# Add a slider for interactive binding in python - plotly

Tags: python, pyspark, plotly, slider

I try to add a slicer in my histogram. Something like this, but with the diference that I can determine the number of binds of the histogram.I work in Microsoft Azure - Databricks

[image]

Here, it is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import last
from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
```

```
data = [["1", "Amit", "DU", "I", "8", "6"],
        ["2", "Mohit", "DU", "I", "4", "2"],
        ["3", "rohith", "BHU", "I", "5", "3"],
        ["4", "sridevi", "LPU", "I", "1", "6"],
        ["1", "sravan", "KLMP", "M", "2", "4"],
        ["5", "gnanesh", "IIT", "M", "6", "8"],
        ["6", "gnadesh", "KLM", "c", "0", "9"]]

columns = ['ID', 'NAME', 'college', 'metric', 'x', 'y']


dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("x",dataframe.x.cast(DoubleType()))
data = dataframe.toPandas()
```

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.express as px

p = plot(
    px.histogram(data_frame = data,x='x',nbins=25, text_auto=True),
    output_type='div'
    )

displayHTML(p)
```

[image]